# ssh dynamically from script from any server

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-server

Ok, I have been searching for few hours and cannot seem to find the solution.

I have a file on a remote server to which one of the local users on that server has write access. I have the credentials. The requirement is:

The shell/perl script should automatically login to the server and write to that file.
The script should work from any server on the network without installing any extra packages as that will require me to sudo which will again ask for password and is therefore not possible from script.

I tried using expect but the server keeps saying spawn not found.

Please advise.

Comment: Using scp and key authentication seems the way to go ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying but I believe you're talking about public key authentication. I did think about that but that is also interactive isn't it?

Comment: using public/private key authentication allows to connect remotely without password. Using scp allows to copy a file from local to server over ssh.

Comment: yes but how do I do that from a script?

Comment: `scp` wouldn't permit appending to an existing file on the remote system. The sftp protocol supports this, but the common command-line utility doesn't appear to provide a command to append to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -l username hostname "password; ~/updatefile.sh params"
```

Doesn't work.

To use the key method, try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ssh-agent /usr/bin/env bash
KEYFILE=`mktemp`
cat << EOF > ${KEYFILE}
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
[.......]
EOF
ssh-add ${KEYFILE}

ssh user host command

# Remove the key file.
rm -f ${KEYFILE}
```

To generate a key for use, refer to the following: http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html

Comment: As soon as I run this from a script, it prompts for a password.

Comment: Oops, sorry.  Edited to provide different method.

Comment: thank you. But it just gives this error and exits:

`Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`

Comment: You'll need to provide the RSA private key.  Edited again to provide information on how to do that.

Comment: that is exactly the problem. The requirement is to have the whole thing automated so as to run from any server without any additional setup outside of the script.
ssh-keygen is interactive

Comment: You can run ssh-keygen and embed the key file in that script .. in the section labeled --- BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY --- ...